# subset a dataframe based on total row condition

Tags: python

I have a dataframe and I want a subset of it based on a condition on row total.

the original dataframe is the below:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({"store" : ["a","b", "c", "d"], "loc" : ["1","2","3","4"], "inv1" : [77,0,0,5], "inv2":[3,0,0,4], "inv3":[3,5,5,4]})
```

I want to add a total row:

```
test.loc["Total", :] = test.sum(axis = 0)
```

now I want to have a subset of my dataframe which the total row of the columns are more than 10.

the output should look like below:
[image: output]

I tried dozens of filtering but none of them resulted in the output.

Comment: "loc" : ["1","2","3","4"] numbers as strings , you meant it correctly?

Comment: yes thats right, those should not be summed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

```
test.loc["Total", test.dtypes == 'object'] = np.nan
test = test.loc[:, (test.dtypes == 'object') | (test.loc["Total"] > 10)]
```

after `test.loc["Total", :] = test.sum(axis = 0)`